# CSS Adjust height of background-color while hovering on weblink (<a> tag)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a Nav menu that includes **ul**, **li** and **a** elements.  I'm trying to produce an effect where hovering over an **a** tag will only change the background color near the text for the link itself instead of the whole **li** area around it.

HTML:

```
 <nav>
    <div class="full_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="drop">Our Team</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">James</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tom</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li><!--End team dropdown  -->
    </ul> 
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:center;
}

nav ul ul {
   display: none;  
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
   display:block;
}

nav ul {
  background: #17A74A;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  display: inline;
  border:0px;
}

nav ul li {
  float:right;
  margin-top:0px;
}

nav ul li a {
  display:block;
  padding:33px 40px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#2D6AF7;
  color:#FFF;
}

nav ul ul {
  background:#17A74A;
  position:absolute;
  top:71px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding:15px 40px;
  color:#FFF;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background:#27BCDD;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
}
```

I thought that by using **nav ul li a:hover** would fix this problem but the whole **li** area is still changing its background color instead of just the immediate area around the link text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve following result? I've removed the padding from your `<a>` elements and added them to the `<li>` elements instead.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/977ufrc9/)

Comment: Yes this what I want!  I knew the fix was something simple such as cutting and pasting padding from one element to another.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the padding to a margin if you don't want the whole thing to change color.  Try this:

```
    nav ul ul li a {
  margin:15px 40px;
  color:#FFF;
}
```